# How do I import a function into a Python package without also importing the file that contains it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, package, python-import

I am working in Python 3.4.2 on Mac OSX and I have a simple version-controlled Python project whose directory/file structure looks like this:

```
vcs_projectname/
    foo/
        __init__.py
        simplefunc.py
    docs/
    other_related_stuff/
```

The `__init__.py` file looks like this:

```
from .simplefunc import helloworld
__all__ = ['helloworld'] # Not sure whether I really need this line...?
```

and the `simplefunc.py` file looks like this:

```
def helloworld():
    print('Hello world!')
```

I test my code by changing to a directory outside of the project hierarchy, setting my `PYTHONPATH` environment variable (in bash) to point at the `vcs_projectname` base directory, and launching [ipython](http://ipython.org/):

```
> cd ~
> export PYTHONPATH=~/vcs_projectname
> ipython
```

Within ipython, I import the package foo and then view its directory structure, with the following result:

```
In [1]: import foo

In [2]: dir(foo)
Out[2]: 
['__all__',
 '__builtins__',
 '__cached__',
 '__doc__',
 '__file__',
 '__loader__',
 '__name__',
 '__package__',
 '__path__',
 '__spec__',
 'helloworld',
 'simplefunc']
```

My question: how do I get rid of the reference to the `simplefunc` file module in the package directory structure?   This is desirable to do because in the best case it is just useless clutter (we don't need it there since the thing that we actually want, the `helloworld()` function, has already been made available at the package level by the `__init__.py` file), and in the worst case it's essentially a reference to an irrelevant implementation detail (the underlying file structure of the project) that could change later, and which I therefore don't want my users to come to expect and rely upon in future versions.

Comment: You can `del`ete the reference. But I wouldn't.

Comment: O.K., I just tried that at the ipython command line ``In [3]: del(foo.simplefunc)`` after the import is actually finished, and technically it does work, but surely there must be a more elegant solution than that?  Isn't there some alternate way that I can structure the ``__init__.py`` file itself to arrive at this same result, which wouldn't be just an ugly kludge or workaround?

Comment: The thing is, the *end goal* you're trying to accomplish is an ugly kludge (in my opinion). You'd be hiding the source code structure from the user, which can make debugging harder than it needs to be and quite frustrating. Use the `_underscore` prefix and **documentation** to make it clear which parts of your code are part of the public API of your package and which are not.

Comment: O.K., so, to be clear, your suggested solution is essentially that if I want to do this, then I should consider renaming the ``simplefunc.py`` file to ``_simplefunc.py`` in order to leave the underlying source code file structure exposed, yet still indicate to the user that it's not intended to be a part of the public API?    Am I characterizing your position correctly?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant, and that would be the obvious way to clearly signal that you consider this module (name / location) an internal detail. But that may often not even be necessary: If you *do* change your code layout at some point and move modules around, merge them etc.., you can always add internal backwards compatibility imports to ensure that code for users that directly used your "internal" modules still works.  See an [example of that in `sqlalchemy`](https://github.com/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/blob/50866d2f857dd45bb2d186a0fa076768437d62a3/lib/sqlalchemy/databases/__init__.py#L8-L19)

Comment: If you write `__all__ = ['helloworld']`, the users should not expect `simplefunc` to be present.

Comment: Both the [`requests`](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/master/requests/__init__.py#L58-L65) and [`sqlalchemy`](https://github.com/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/blob/master/lib/sqlalchemy/__init__.py#L9-L121) libraries are excellent examples of how to structure large codebases and split the code up in enough submodules and yet still maintain a clean, well documented API. Particularly compare their docs ([requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) | [SQLAlchemy](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/)) vs. the way the code has been structured and how they use internal imports.

Answer (score 3):

What you're trying to do is not possible elegantly. As @Lukas mentioned, there are hacks that can accomplish this.

Instead what I've been following is, create a sub-package named `_private` and put all such modules in there. That way when user imports the package, all the exposed APIs are available and private APIs are tucked away inside `_private`.

**Example:**

```
foo/
    __init__.py
    _private/
        __init__.py
        test1.py
        test2.py
```

**`foo/__init__.py`:**

```
from _private import bar, baz
```

**`foo/_private/__init__.py`:**

```
from test1 import bar
from test2 import baz
```

**`foo/_private/test1.py`:**

```
def bar():
    print "bar"
```

**`foo/_private/test2.py`:**

```
def baz():
    print "baz"
```

**Importing `foo`:**

```
>>> import foo
>>> dir(foo)
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '_private', 'bar', 'baz']
```

Answer (score 2):

> how do I get rid of the reference to the simplefunc file module in the package directory structure?

You can accomplish your stated goal by adding `del simplefunc` to your `foo/__init__.py`, like so:

```
from  .simplefunc import helloworld
del simplefunc
__all__ = ['helloworld'] # Not sure whether I really need this line...?
```